# Docker: creating multiple containers from only one image

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

**Situation**: I want a docker structure where I can have different projects under a common root. (normally with a mean structure) but using different images (not all in a mean image). I want all the projects shared in the container that I create for a specific project but only launch the configuration of the project that I want. The image just install the basic dependences and the modules specifics for every apps are installed by the docker-compose override.

That is my ideal structure:

```
apps  
| +--app1  
| |  +--node_modules //empty in host  
| |  +--package.json  
| |  +--docker-compose.app1.yml  //override compose
| |  +--index.js  
| |  +--...  
| +--app2  
| |  +--node_modules  //empty in host  
| |  +--...  
| ....  
| +--node_modules //global node_modules folder (empty in host)  
| docker-compose.yml //principal compose  
| Dockerfile  //my personalized nodejs image config
```

I'm using a intermediate solution:

```
apps  
| +--app1  
| |  +--index.js  
| |  +--...  
| +--app2  
| |  +--index.js  
| |  +--...  
| ....  
| +--node_modules //global for all projects  (empty in host)  
| docker-compose.yml //principal compose 
| docker-compose.app1.yml //override for app1
| docker-compose.app2.yml //override for app2
| .... 
| Dockerfile  //my personalized nodejs image config
```

**DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM node  #base image  
# User no root
RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false apps 
ENV HOME=/home/apps #my home folder
# Copy modules config and dependencies
COPY package.json npm-shrinkwrap.json $HOME/
RUN chown -R apps:apps $HOME/  #changing permissions no root user
WORKDIR $HOME
RUN npm install #install modules
RUN npm cache clean #clean cache

# user no root active
USER apps
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
   build: .
    image: myNodejs:0.1
    container_name: my_nodejs
    volumes:
      - .:/home/apps #sharing my host route with the container
      - /home/apps/curso_mean/node_modules # route to node_modules
```

**Docker-compose.app1**

```
version: "2"
services:
 web:
   container_name: app1
   command: node app1/index.js
   ports:
    - "3000:3000"
   environment:
    - NODE_ENV=development
```

Command to launch app1

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.app1.yml up -d
```

The problem here is that I have the same node_modules for all the projects and are installed in the image (I would prefer install that in the compose) but I only use a image and I can have different configuration for every project.

**Questions**

- Is possible have the first structure?
- Is possible install the specific modules in the docker-compose override executing more than one command or for other way and keep the global node_modules installed in the image?

Comment: I'm facing the same situation right now, but it's rare to find resource for this common case online.